# How do you implement a single static method that adds two numbers of any type (Double, Integer)?

Tags: java

I need one static method that simply adds two different numbers together and returns the result. However, it needs to be able to accept different types of numbers such as Integer and Doubles which is where I am getting stuck. Here is the main method that I have which, cannot be changed.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Double answer1 = add(2, 7);
    Number answer2 = add(new Integer(4), new Double(5.2));
    double answer3 = add(8, 1.3);
    System.out.println(answer1 + " " + answer2 + " " + answer3);
} 

public static Double add(Double num1, Integer num2)
{
    return num1 + num2;
}
```

The method above has the correct body I just don't know what should be where Double is after static. Is there some type that accommodates for both doubles and integers?

New situation:

```
public static double add(Number num1, Number num2)
{
    return num1 + num2; //error is here
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the common baseclass [`Number`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html).

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 5;
        double y = 10;
        System.out.println(getDoubleValue(x, y));
    }

    private static double getDoubleValue(Number x, Number y){
        return x.doubleValue() + y.doubleValue();
    }
}
```

Output:

> 15.0

Comment: The main method doesn't have to be changed at all. I just changed it a little for an easy example. You can call my `getDoubleValue()` method with your own `main` method.

Comment: You have to call a value on `num1` and `num2`. I suggest you use the `.doubleValue()` to prevent rounding errors from an integer. Afterwards your code will work.

Comment: Please make an effort. Just name your method `add()` instead of `getDoubleValue()`.

Comment: Thanks! I tried creating a new variable of double type and returning that but it didn't work. the .doubleValue() works perfectly thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
 public void draw(String s) {
    ...
 }
 public void draw(int i) {
    ...
 }
 public void draw(double f) {
    ...
 }
 public void draw(int i, double f) {
    ...
 }
```

Look at the following link

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Means you have to use method overloading

Answer (score 1):

You should use method overloading.

```
Double Foo()  // Version with no arguments
{
}

Double Foo(int arg) // Version with a single int
{
}

Double add(Double num1, Integer num2) // Version with integer  and double parameters
{
}
```

Comment: Part of the tast is not to use an overloadded method. Sorry missed that out.

Answer (score 0):

You could use method overloading for that. Creating an identical method with different datatype :)